# Using Multiple Value on a Variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am creating a stored procedure and i need to have a variable of some sort contain multiple values. I have tried using a table variable but that isnt what im looking for. The reason for this is because i have to check multiple values from a select query and then use an if statement on these values.

The code that i need the variable for is :

```
If @SplitVal = 1
Begin
    Insert into SpecDetailsExt (SrecId, SplitVal, Acknowledged,Required, [Drawings Produced]) 
    Select DISTINCT SpecDetails.SrecId, '1', @MoveToOrder, @RequiredDate, @Drawings
    FROM   SpecDetails INNER JOIN Products ON SpecDetails.ProductRef = Products.CDF_Code_Tx 
    WHERE (SpecDetails.QuoteNo = @Qno) 
End
ELSE
Begin
    Insert into SpecDetailsExt (SrecId, SplitVal, Acknowledged, Required, [Drawings Produced])
    Select DISTINCT SpecDetails.SrecId, '1', @MoveToOrder, @RequiredDate, @Drawings 
    FROM   SpecDetails INNER JOIN Products ON SpecDetails.ProductRef = Products.CDF_Code_Tx 
    WHERE (SpecDetails.QuoteNo = @Qno)

    Insert into SpecDetailsExt (SrecId, SplitVal, Acknowledged, Required, [Drawings Produced]) 
    Select DISTINCT SpecDetails.SrecId, '2', @MoveToOrder, @RequiredDate, @Drawings
FROM   SpecDetails 
          INNER JOIN Products ON SpecDetails.ProductRef = Products.CDF_Code_Tx 
    WHERE (SpecDetails.QuoteNo = @Qno) 
End
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by "have multiple values"? A variable only has one value at a time. Do you mean you need multiple variables? Why would a temp table or simply multiple variables not work? Also, from your code it's not clear which variable you are expecting to "have multiple values". If what you mean is that for each insert you need to store the MoveToOrder, RequiredDate, Drawings, and Qno, then you can do this by using a temp table and then merging into your real table by joining on SrecId (assuming that is the primary key).

Comment: I need `@SplitVal` to have multiple values. Or at least a way of assigning a value to it and then looping through and assigning a different variable then using that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass in a string as a ? seperated list, then create a UDF for splitting it out.  Or just split it in your code, if you dont want a UDF.